# Difference between Affero-GPL and GPLv3

Tags: licensing

What is the difference between the [Affero General Public License](http://www.affero.org/oagpl.html) and the [GNU General Public License (GPL)](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131264/what-constitutes-distributing-for-lgpl-v3

Comment: @MikeWilliamson there is pretty significant community consensus on meta that these questions are off-topic -- you can read more and join the discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280151/how-do-we-handle-ethical-legal-questions) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272705/does-a-question-about-a-programming-lawsuit-belong-on-stack-overflow-or-its-lega) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288222/3093387).

Comment: The affrero AGPL should rather be compared to the GNU AGPL version 3 https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html

Comment: The affero.org domain no longer serves licensing content. Please link to https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html

Comment: There are two groups that would be interested in an answer to this question - those using software with one of these licenses, and those choosing one for their own project. The question would be closable just for failing to make the distinction.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Assume the following:

You are developing a server side application in GPL. Now this application serves HTML and not an executable which is directly executed on your machine. That means that another guy could take the GPL code, adapt it and does not necessarily need to publish it. Ie. he can create the identical service using your software without violating the GPL. (Although THEN he cannot publish the software itself i.e. selling)

Not so with the [AGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.fr.html).

This hole in the GPL is often called "Application Service Provider" hole.

Search for "Why AGPL" or "AGPL vs. GPL" for some real projects who have problems with GPL.

Public web application that uses the AGPL are listed [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_under_the_GNU_AGPL).

Comment: I thought GPL allowed you to sell the software or a modified version of the software as long as you make it GPL too. Is that not the case?

Comment: @conradk yes, sure you can sell but the example was about using the software hidden behind a service. I will rephrase to 'Although THEN he cannot publish the software itself (i.e. selling)'

Comment: I'm sorry, but I disagree again. He can sell it, as long as it is licensed under GPL. Well, that's how I understand the license. No?

Comment: I do not explain the 'selling' here, I explain that for this guy it would be possible to use the GPL code in his closed source service WITHOUT violating the license and WITHOUT the necessity to publish the code. This might not be intented from the original author.

Comment: I think that sentence is very confusing. What does "Although then he cannot publish the software itself" mean?

Comment: @conradk, it means "he cannot publish the software itself, if he wants to keep it closed source." (but he still can use it server side).

Comment: @SyedLavasani: That is more clear indeed. Thanks. Because he can publish it under AGPL terms and sell it, I think.

Comment: "or just read this" link is broken

Answer (score 28):

See http://www.gnu.org/licenses/licenses.html#AGPL

> The GNU Affero General Public License is based on the GNU GPL, but has an additional term to allow users who interact with the licensed software over a network to receive the source for that program. We recommend that people consider using the GNU AGPL for any software which will commonly be run over a network.

Comment: See also https://choosealicense.com/licenses/agpl-3.0/